# Windows 10 en 2 discos duros (Arranque dual)

Tags: windows

Tengo un problema con el arranque dual en unPC con 2 discos duros (un SSD y un HDD).

Ambos discos tienen como S.O. Windows 10 instalado, y quiero hacer que siempre que encienda el PC me pregunte que disco (Windows) quiero arrancar.

He configurado las entradas en el bootloader con EasyBCD en el disco que la Bios UEFI tiene como prioridad de arranque, pero no consigo que cada vez que encienda el PC me pregunte que Windows (disco duro) arrancar, sino que arranca directamente el ultimo disco que haya usado.

La única forma de que me aparezca el administrador de arranque de Windows para poder elegir un disco duro u otro es cuando reinicio el PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El arranque rápido de Windows creo que evita que puedas arrancar con el otro disco. De hecho creo que ni puedes entrar en la bios.

Si te vas a las opciones de recuperación y le dices que haga un arranque limpio creo que sí te funcionarán las opciones de arranque.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora si tras deshabilitar el arranque rápido de Windows como bien dices, todo funciona perfectamente.